# Can't change tag content with innerHTML and innerText

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

I'm creating an HTML/JS calculator, and my main result is in the div, but I can't change it with eventListeners. I tried to get `innerHTML` and `innerText` of the result. And tried to change it in several ways but unfortunately, it didn't change the result content.

Here is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="result">0</div>

        <div class="buttons" id="clearOne">C</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="clearAll">&#8592;</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="random">RAND</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="equal">=</div>

        <div class="buttons" id="one">1</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="two">2</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="three">3</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="multiply">X</div>

        <div class="buttons" id="four">4</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="five">5</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="six">6</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="division">/</div>

        <div class="buttons" id="seven">7</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="eight">8</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="nine">9</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="minus">-</div>

        <div class="buttons" id="doubleZero">00</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="zero">0</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="dot">.</div>
        <div class="buttons" id="plus">+</div>
    </div>

    <script src="./calculator.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
let result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;

let one = document.getElementById('one');
let two = document.getElementById('two');
let three = document.getElementById('three');
let four = document.getElementById('four');
let five = document.getElementById('five');
let six = document.getElementById('six');
let seven = document.getElementById('seven');
let eight = document.getElementById('eight');
let nine = document.getElementById('nine');
let zero = document.getElementById('zero');
let doubleZero = document.getElementById('doubleZero');
let dot = document.getElementById('dot');

let clearOne = document.getElementById('clearOne');
let clearAll = document.getElementById('clearAll');
let random_btn = document.getElementById('random');
let equal = document.getElementById('equal');
let multiply = document.getElementById('multiply');
let divison = document.getElementById('division');
let minus = document.getElementById('minus');
let plus = document.getElementById('plus');

const numberEvents = (btn, value) => {
    return btn.addEventListener(
        "click",
        () => {
            if (result === '0'){
                result = "";
                console.log('test');
                result + `${value}`;
            } else {
                console.log('test1');
                result + `${value}`;
            }
        }
    )
}

numberEvents(one, '1');
numberEvents(two, '2');
numberEvents(three, '3');
numberEvents(four, '4');
numberEvents(five, '5');
numberEvents(six, '6');
numberEvents(seven, '7');
numberEvents(eight, '8');
numberEvents(nine, '9');
```

The problem is not in the `numberEvents` function. I tried to write `addEventListener` separately too.

Here is the full program in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-wxmh8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You need to set/get `innerHTML` explicitly when you want to change it or get current value. `variable = ...innerHTML` just sets `variable` to the current value. There is no binding between `variable` and `innerHTML` changing one isnt going to change the other. You also dont save `result + \`${value}\`;` to anything

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry, can you show it in the codesandbox that I mentioned in the latest edit? I don't understand exactly what I did wrong :/

Comment: @PatrickEvans Oh, I get it now, thanks for the explanation very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` — is just a string. When you write later `result + value` — it's just an operation, without any assignment. `result = result + value` wouldn't change anything as well - it would change the saved string, but not the actual "innerHTML".

You must save an HTML-object to a variable, and check it's updated textContent each time instead:

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result');

let one = document.getElementById('one');
let two = document.getElementById('two');
let three = document.getElementById('three');
let four = document.getElementById('four');
let five = document.getElementById('five');
let six = document.getElementById('six');
let seven = document.getElementById('seven');
let eight = document.getElementById('eight');
let nine = document.getElementById('nine');
let zero = document.getElementById('zero');
let doubleZero = document.getElementById('doubleZero');
let dot = document.getElementById('dot');

let clearOne = document.getElementById('clearOne');
let clearAll = document.getElementById('clearAll');
let random_btn = document.getElementById('random');
let equal = document.getElementById('equal');
let multiply = document.getElementById('multiply');
let divison = document.getElementById('division');
let minus = document.getElementById('minus');
let plus = document.getElementById('plus');

const numberEvents = (btn, value) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (result.textContent === '0') {
      result.textContent = "";
      console.log('test');
      result.textContent += value; 
      // The same as    result.textContent = result.textContent + value
    } else {
      console.log('test1');
      result.textContent += value;
    }
  });
}

numberEvents(one, '1');
numberEvents(two, '2');
numberEvents(three, '3');
numberEvents(four, '4');
numberEvents(five, '5');
numberEvents(six, '6');
numberEvents(seven, '7');
numberEvents(eight, '8');
numberEvents(nine, '9');
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="result">0</div>

  <div class="buttons" id="clearOne">C</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="clearAll">&#8592;</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="random">RAND</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="equal">=</div><br>

  <div class="buttons" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="three">3</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="multiply">X</div><br>

  <div class="buttons" id="four">4</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="five">5</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="six">6</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="division">/</div><br>

  <div class="buttons" id="seven">7</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="eight">8</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="nine">9</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="minus">-</div><br>

  <div class="buttons" id="doubleZero">00</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="dot">.</div>
  <div class="buttons" id="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

But it's bad practice to work with ids, if you have multiple buttons with the same functions. A little demo of alternative solution:

```js
let res = document.getElementById('result');
let num = document.querySelectorAll('.type-number');

for( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ){
  num[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( res.textContent == 0 ) {
      res.textContent = this.textContent;
    } else {
      res.textContent += this.textContent;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.type-number {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p id="result">0</p>

<button class="type-number">1</button>
<button class="type-number">2</button>
<button class="type-number">3</button><br>
<button class="type-number">4</button>
<button class="type-number">5</button>
<button class="type-number">6</button><br>
<button class="type-number">7</button>
<button class="type-number">8</button>
<button class="type-number">9</button><br>
<button class="type-number">0</button>
```

Comment: This method with a loop seems great, but it doesn't work, is something wrong?

Comment: «Run Code Snippet» here - it works... Maybe something gone wrong on copy-paste stage))

Comment: `querySelectorAll(".type-number");` — it's a class selector... your number-buttons must have a unique class, to collect them with querySelectorAll... And loop already adds all required event listeners... you didn't need to put the loop inside the `numberEvents` function... if must work separately.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I made a mistake. I wrote `type-buttons` instead of `type-number` XD...Instead of just my code you fixed it and improve it. Thank you very much!